# Nested presenters with GWTP

Tags: gwt-platform

I have content slots in my mainpresenter, how can i put, when app load, put the home presenter in one slot and the menu slot in the another ?

or isn't possible?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can ! In the following example code, I assume that your HomePresenter is a place and extends Presenter, and your MenuPresenter extends PresenterWidget.
In your MainPresenter :

```
@ContentSlot public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> MAIN_SLOT = new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();  
@ContentSlot public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> MENU_SLOT = new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();

@Override
protected void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();
    setInSlot(MENU_SLOT, menuPresenter);
}
```

In your HomePresenter :

```
@Override
protected void revealInParent() {
    RevealContentEvent.fire(this, MainPresenter.MAIN_SLOT, this);
}
```

Then in MainView :

```
@UiField Panel mainContainer;
@UiField Panel menuContainer;

@Override
public void setInSlot(Object slot, Widget content) {
    if (slot == MainPresenter.MAIN_SLOT) {
        mainContainer.clear();
        mainContainer.add(content);
    } else if (slot == MainPresenter.MENU_SLOT) {
        menuContainer.clear();
        menuContainer.add(content);
    } else {
        super.setInSlot(slot, content);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mikael, your answer really helps. But I have a question. Here what you do is add-remove-add-remove.. content(Widget) to mainContainer(Panel). Isn't this an overhead? Can't we do something like hide-show of content(Widget)?

Comment: @RAS Actually, I don't see how to do it in any other way. The setInSlot() method has to do with the composition of a UI with separate presenters, so at some point you will have to inject a widget in a panel. Also, clearing a panel doesn't mean that the contained widget is discarded, it can be re-injected later.

Comment: @MikaelCouzic, thanks for your reply. I understood your point.

Answer (score 1):

For users of GWTP 1.5+, note that a lot of new changes have been introduced to slots, and revealing presenters.  The case in question may now be accomplished using a NestedSlot for the page content and a PermanentSlot for a menu that you want displayed on all of your pages.

Fortunately, these changes are well documented.  See the [GWTP slot documentation](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/core/slots/) for an explanation on the new slot types with examples on how to use them.

Comment: Reading through the documentation now for two days but I still can't answer [this rather simple question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729549/how-to-use-gwtp-for-a-listview-widget) ^^